# How to get data form Google Cloud Pub/Sub to a local RabbitMQ (AMQP) server

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-platform

I am publishing serial data to the Google PubSub system, and am needing to send that data to a local RabbitMQ (AMQP) server.  Does anyone have any thoughts or know of a method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would even want to do that, but I think the only way to do it is to create a separate subscription in a topic from which you want to send the messages, then write a script that would pull the messages from it, send them to rabbit and acknowledge them.